# azure centos update: Error: Multilib version problems found. libsss_idmap

Tags: azure, centos, centos7

Azure centos 7 VM has update issues with Multilib version problems found for libsss_idmap

Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

```
     1. You have an upgrade for libsss_idmap which is missing some
        dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
        solve this by installing an older version of libsss_idmap of the
        different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
        yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
        requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
        --exclude libsss_idmap.otherarch ... this should give you an error
        message showing the root cause of the problem.

     2. You have multiple architectures of libsss_idmap installed, but
        yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
        If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
        can remove the one with the missing update and everything
        will work.

     3. You have duplicate versions of libsss_idmap installed already.
        You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).

   Protected multilib versions: libsss_idmap-1.16.5-10.el7_9.11.x86_64 != libsss_idmap- 1.16.5-10.el7_9.10.i686
   Error: Protected multilib versions: libsss_nss_idmap-1.16.5-10.el7_9.11.x86_64 != libsss_nss_idmap-1.16.5-10.el7_9.10.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

edit CentOS-Base.repo and comment out the MS Azure trafficmanager.net URL.

```sh
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

comment out with (#) baseurl and remove comment of mirrorlist

```conf
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://olcentgbl.trafficmanager.net/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

credit to binaryflow at : https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=78483&sid=ca05b4af61e270f4cc074f1f2105d088&start=10